# Change text color if last image in banner is active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bxslider

html:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
<a id="selected" href="#">details</a>
```

I use **bxslider** and I want if last `image` is `active` `a#selected` will have a class `.select` is this possible

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/83/

js

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true,
});

$(document).ready(function(){
                if (slider.active.index == 0){
                $('#selected').addClass("select");
            }

            });
```

Comment: since bxslider does not go by `active` state, but goes by `left` attr, this logic would not work

Comment: thank you for the opinion, but i hope there is anyway to achieve what i want. sometime I need to think the impossible to have self improvement. ones again thank you..

Comment: you might have to look into some callback. May be `onSlideNext`, figureout the last element and add css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onAfterSlide` callback to the `bxSlider`.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    onAfterSlide: function (currentSlide) {
        if(currentSlide == $('.bxslider').children('li.pager').length -1) {
            $('#selected').addClass("select");
        } else {
            $('#selected').removeClass("select");
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/rAYDr/1/)**

Comment: hi i try your code but unfortunately i can find where I'm doing wrong its not working... but in your demo work perfectly.

Comment: could you please put the code on fiddle, it will help me to understand better.

Comment: thank you for your reply maybe i need first to try it by my self, maybe this is conflict with another jquery.. thank you very much

Comment: hi if ok with you can you try it in your local because the problem occur in when i implement it in my local files..